# Redefining a PHP variable by referencing the variable in a function?

Tags: php

Gee Wiz finding the vocab to express the question can be pretty tricky, but hopefully you can tell me what's wrong with referencing a variable in a function in order to change it.

Example:

```
    <?php
$a = 5;
$something = 5;

function changeIt($it){
    global $a;
    $it = $it * $a;
};

changeIt($something);

echo $something;
    ?>
```

This returns 5, so the global variable $something hasn't been redefined.

Comment: ... not calling `changeIt` for one, not using reference variables for another. http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php . Use `&$it` in your function declaration instead.

Comment: Your not calling `changeIt()`. Furthermore, what do you want to change?

Comment: As both minitech and Jason noted you are doing a number of thing incorrectly. It would be very helpful if you told us what exactly you are trying to achieve, forget about the code.

Comment: Be more specific in what you are trying to do. Are you trying to return the value of $it? make sure you `return $it` . Are you trying to modify the value of the variable that $it references in a pass by reference type of way? Make sure you specify that you are passing by reference `function changeIt(&$it)` .

Comment: Any explanation on the downvotes, people?

Comment: yeah thanks I had a look at the manuals etc.. which is how I ended up here. Please see my adjusted code. I am trying to redefine the global variable through the function. I am also trying to do it by referencing the variable itself.

Comment: I have Googled this issue to death so the insinuation that my comment is unresearched is off the mark. This should be a common use of functions in PHP...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass `$it` by reference, and also call `changeIt`:

```
<?php
    function changeIt(&$it){
       global $a;
       $it = $it * $a;
    }

    $a = 5;
    $something = 5;

    changeIt($something);
?>
```

http://ideone.com/9RQQW

Comment: Just guessing that he wants to do `changeIt($something)`, since he's used `$a` as a global, but `$something` is unused.

Comment: +1 for the correct answer and also for including the totally unused $something in it...

Comment: Hey please check my code above and please tell me why you need that ampersand?

Comment: @3Dom: You need the ampersand to pass the variable by reference. See the link I posted as a comment to your question.

Comment: Passing by reference. Now there's another obscure operation I wouldn't have thought necessary, but hey, super duper spot on mate. You have made me a happy man.